# On replacing this Fragment, the GUI shows nothing but still replacing the fragment and there is no crash

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction

[Screenshotof logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AJlU.png)

[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKG5a.jpg)

As this is my main Activity.

```
package com.appshep.fbalbumdownloader.activities;
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProfileListener {

@Bind(R.id.tabs)
TabLayout tabLayout;
@Bind(R.id.viewpager)
ViewPager viewPager;

AccessToken token;
private String imageURL;
private String userID;
private String userName;
GraphRequest graphRequest;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    //initialization
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    token=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    userID=token.getUserId();

    graphRequest= new GraphRequest(token, "/me", null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
            try
            {
                if(graphResponse!=null)
                {

                    JSONObject obj = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                    userName= obj.getString("name");
                    imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID
                            + "/picture?height=100&width=100";
                    DownloadManager manager= new DownloadManager(ProfileActivity.this);
                   //hack created
                   // manager.setStr(imageURL);
                    manager.execute(imageURL);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    graphRequest.executeAsync();


    //Define the number of tabs by setting appropriate fragment and tab name.
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new LoggedinFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new MyVideosFragment(), "Videos");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public void onSuccess(final Bitmap bitmap) {

    Bitmap output=getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(output);

}

@Override
public void onFailure(String string) {

}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 95;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

This is the current Fragment where I have a buttons. And I want this Fragment to be replaced by another Fragment after having a click on it.  I guess I've a problem in replacing the Fragment or in its onCreateView(). Also I can't use the Fragment ID because I'm not using Fragment Widget in Layout.

```
public class LoggedinFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String userName;
    Button loadAlbums;
    MyAlbumsFragment fragment;
    GridOfPictures fragmentGrid;
    FragmentManager manager;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction;
    public LoggedinFragment() {
        //Empty constructor is required
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_loggedin, container, false);
        getButton(view);
        return view;
    }
    public void replaceFragment()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            //fragment= new MyAlbumsFragment();
            fragmentGrid= new GridOfPictures();

            manager=getFragmentManager();
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            //transaction.replace(R.id.com_facebook_fragment_container,fragment,"My Albums");
            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            //transaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, fragmentGrid, "Album");
            transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), fragmentGrid, "My Albums");

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.my_photos_btn:
                replaceFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.friends_photos_btn:
                replaceFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.my_tags_btn:
                replaceFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.tell_friend_btn:
                replaceFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.more_apps_btn:
                replaceFragment();
                break;
        }
    }
   @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    sharedPreferences= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("UserName"))
    {
        userName=sharedPreferences.getString("UserName","");
    }
    textView.setText(userName);

  }

  public void getButton(View view){
    loadAlbums=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.my_photos_btn);
    loadAlbums.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
}
```

This is the Fragment I want to be replaced by my first Fragment that I have created programatically not by Fragment Widget in the Layout.

```
    public class GridOfPictures extends Fragment {

//Empty constructor is required
public GridOfPictures() {
}
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_of_pictures,container, false);
    //Fetch that GridView
    GridView gridView=(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    //Use rootView to get context instead of getActivity()
    gridView.setAdapter( new ImageAdapter(rootView.getContext()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

This is the FragmentAdapter named as ImageAdapter.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
//Reference to our images
private Integer[] thumbIDs= {R.drawable.bride,R.drawable.images,R.drawable.feet,
                             R.drawable.tech, R.drawable.islamic, R.drawable.bangles};

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return thumbIDs.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(320, 320));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

    }
    else
    {
        imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(thumbIDs[i]);
    return imageView;
}
}
```

Comment: where is the call for replacing fragment?

Comment: I just didn't mention that Code here. but have written in the Fragment.

Comment: You need to put that code here actual class

Comment: public void getButton(View view){
        loadAlbums=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.my_photos_btn);
        loadAlbums.setOnClickListener(this);
    } this was the function you're asking for. It has that call to initiate onClickListener.

Comment: Did you try debuging it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a container for your fragments. Create a new Fragment like this:
my_container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

MyContainer.java:

```
public class MyFragmentContainer extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_container,parent,false);

    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment =new LoggedInFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.myContainer,fragment).commit();

    return view;
}
}
```

This will be the container that holds your fragments. Replacing the fragments inside the container will work like this:

```
public void replaceFragment()
{
    try
    {

        fragmentGrid= new GridOfPictures();

        manager=getFragmentManager();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.myContainer, fragmentGrid, "My Albums");

        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this approach. But this gonna coast me a crash. Because I'm using ViewPager and ToolBar Tags in my main_activity layout. I've created these Fragments programatically and their layouts consist of different widgets inside a RelativeLayout. Can't switch to this approach. Please tell something why I'm having a blank fragment on replacement.

Comment: Can you post screenshots? Or can you post the log of the crash caused by this approach

Comment: Done. Now you may see that.

Comment: @HafizaSaniaSaleem if you want to replace the viewpager completely with another fragment then you need to pass a fragment containing your viewpager in a container (like i showed you on my answer). Check the Schedule fragments [here](https://github.com/DrilonBlakqori/EventBlank/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/zagapps/eventblank/fragments) . I had a fragment with a viewpager inside of it. I put the fragment inside of a container and the childs of the viewpager were also fragments. Clicking on one of the items in the child items would add a new fragment in top of the viewpager.